# React Native Basic App crashing on google nexus 5s and Redmi K20

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I created a basic react app On using it on redmi k20 as physical using usb debugging as well as nexus5s on emulator it crashes without showing any error

app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';


const App = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Ross Wala Haiii;</Text>
    </View>
  );
};


export default App;
```

app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile


project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"


def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.storiesapp"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }

    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
      exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

It shows:

```
java.lang.Unsatisfiedlinkerror: couldn't find DSO to load:

libfbjni.so result: 0

at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.doLoadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:825) e(SoLoader.java:825) at

com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoName(S oLoader.java:673) at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.jav a:611) at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.jav a:559) at

com.facebook.soloader.NativeLoaderToSoLoader Delegate.

loadLibrary(NativeLoaderToSoLoaderDelegate.java:25) at com.facebook.soloader.nativeloader. NativeLoader.loadLibr ary(NativeLoader.java:44) at com.facebook.jni.HybridData.<clinit>(HybridData.java:

34) at com.facebook.flipper.android. Flippers Thread.run(Flipper The ead.java:25)
```

I am using RN 16.13.1
on windows 10

It is my first experience with react native and may lack basic react native knowledge
Please Help

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is very similar to an issue opened on [github](https://github.com/facebook/SoLoader/issues/55). You may want to subscribe to the thread for future updates on fixing the `SoLoader` issue.

To fix this, one of the developers added the following under `android/app/build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
   implementation 'com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.9.0+'
   ...
}
```

As for me, because of my other dependencies relying on `SoLoader`, i have added the following above my declared dependencies under `android/app/build.gradle`:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force "com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.8.2"
    }
}

dependencies {
    ...
}
```

My app now runs well without `SoLoader` issue on Nexus 5s emulator.

Comment: Do both methods not work for you? Even after running `./gradlew clean` and rebuild the entire project?